# Query is summing values multiple times

Tags: sql, summary

Hi my query below is summing multiple values based on @cropseasons in my table. Since i have 4 crop seasons it seems to be multiplying the values by 4 since i have crop season as 1, 2, 3 or 4. All i want is values for 1 crop season. Can anyone assist? I have crop season in both tables.

```
With Summary as (
    Select B_NAME as Branch, LOC as Location
          ,SUM(payment) as Gallons
          ,SUM(case when printed = 1 THEN Fee ELSE NULL END) as FeeCollected
          ,SUM(case when printed = 0 THEN Fee ELSE NULL END) as FeeNotCollected
          ,SUM(case when printed = 1 THEN Payment ELSE NULL END) as GallonsIssued
          ,SUM(case when printed = 0 THEN Payment ELSE NULL END) as GallonsNotIssued
    From SicbWeeklyDeliveriesFuelArchive F Inner Join FarmerGroups G ON G.BSI_CODE = F.BSI_CODE

    Where F.CROP_SEASON = @cropseason

    Group By B_NAME, LOC
    )

SELECT Branch
      ,Location
      ,Gallons
      ,GallonsIssued
      ,GallonsNotIssued
      ,FeeCollected
      ,FeeNotCollected
      ,((GallonsIssued/Gallons) * 100) as pct_GallonsCollected
    FROM Summary
    Order by Location, Branch
```

### SicbWeeklyDeliveriesFuelArchive

```
+-------+----------+-------------+-----+---------+------+-------------+---------+
|  ID   | BSI_CODE |   B_NAME    | LOC | PAYMENT | FEE  | CROP_SEASON | PRINTED |
+-------+----------+-------------+-----+---------+------+-------------+---------+
| 18735 |     2176 | SAN NARCISO | CZ  |      85 |  8.5 |           4 |       0 |
| 18738 |     2176 | SAN NARCISO | CZ  |      65 |  6.5 |           4 |       0 |
| 18739 |    10494 | SAN NARCISO | CZ  |      85 |  8.5 |           3 |       0 |
+-------+----------+-------------+-----+---------+------+-------------+---------+
```

### FarmerGroups

```
+-------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|  ID   | BSI_CODE | CROP_SEASON |   BRANCH    |
+-------+----------+-------------+-------------+
| 10473 |     2176 |           4 | SAN NARCISO |
| 11478 |     2176 |           3 | SAN NARCISO |
| 12787 |    10494 |           4 | SAN ROMAN   |
+-------+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: We don't know your tables. There are two tables in your query, but you have not qualified the columns. You have `b_name`, but is it `f.b_name` or `g.b_name`? Is it `f.loc`or `g.loc? `f.printed` or `g.printed`? ... You have resticted your weekly rows to one crop season, but you seem to get multiple farmer groups for one such row. You join on BSI code, which is probably not unique in the farmer groups table. Thus you get multiple matches. Without knowing more about your tables, we cannot help here. If the farmer groups table has a crop season column, too, you forgot it in your `ON` clause.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to run the query without aggregation, i.e. just `select * from sicbweeklydeliveriesfuelarchive f inner join farmergroups g on g.bsi_code = f.bsi_code where f.crop_season = @cropseason order by b_name, loc` to see on what data set you build your sums.

Comment: @ivias . . . No one can really answer your question.  As Thorsten points out it is inscrutable.  *Qualify* all column references so it is clear what tables they come from.  Provide sample data and desired results, so we can see what you are trying to explain.  You should also provide an appropriate database tag.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I have added the tables and sample data. I also tried and added F.CROP_SEASON = cropseason on the same line as the FROM statement eg. From SicbWeeklyDeliveriesFuelArchive F Inner Join FarmerGroups G ON G.BSI_CODE = F.BSI_CODE AND F.CROP_SEASON = cropseason but still doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your join criteria is incomplete. The tables share `BSI_CODE` and `CROP_SEASON`, so I guess you want:

```
FROM sicbweeklydeliveriesfuelarchive f 
JOIN farmergroups g ON g.bsi_code = f.bsi_code AND g.crop_season = f.crop_season
WHERE f.crop_season = @cropseason
```

But that's just guessing. Only you know how the tables are really related, what their rows represent, what columns make a row unique and what result you are actually after. Why do you join `farmergroups` at all? It looks like you are not really using the table in your query.